# Find number of tangent to given curve

Tags: derivatives, tangent-line

The number of tangent to curve $x^\frac{3}{2} +y^\frac{3}{2} = a^\frac{3}{2}$ where the tangents are equally inclined to axes, is

My work
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\sqrt\frac{x}{y}$$ 
From above we can say that $$x,y>0$$
So x and y must lie in first coordinate .
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\sqrt\frac{x}{y}=1$$
$$\sqrt\frac{x}{y}=-1$$
This is not possible
$$\sqrt\frac{x}{y}=1$$
So there will be only one tangent$$ \sqrt x=\sqrt y$$ 
$$x=y$$
Please tell me whether I am correct or not.

Answer (score 1):

> Continuing from $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=-\sqrt{\dfrac{x}{y}}\tag{1}$

Yes you are correct, except that $x,y>0$ and $\sqrt{x}=\sqrt{y}$

Because when $x,y<0$, $\frac{x}{y} >0$ and $\sqrt\frac{x}{y}=1$ doesn't imply that $\sqrt{x}=\sqrt{y}$. For the sake of contradiction see that $\sqrt\frac{-2}{-2}=\sqrt{1}=1$, but $\sqrt{-2}=\sqrt{-2}$, is not defined, when $x,y$ are real.

So there is only one tangent in the first and third quadrant passing through the origin.

---

**Update:**

But assumption that $(1)$ is correct is wrong because $$x^\frac{3}{2} +y^\frac{3}{2} = a^\frac{3}{2} \Rightarrow \dfrac{dx}{dy}=-\dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{y}} \text{ or } \dfrac{dx}{dy}=-\sqrt{\dfrac{x}{y}} \text{ when } x,y >0$$

> So, $x,y>0$ and the required tangent is the first quadrant.

---

**Note:**

There is nothing wrong with your solution except the above mentioned step(see **Update**). I just wanted to show you how a false step leads to other steps, the truth of which can't be determined, as logically it is true by default.

---

**Advice:**

Just in case this:

> $$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\sqrt\frac{x}{y}$$ 
>   From above we can say that $$x,y>0$$
>   So x and y must lie in first coordinate .

meant this:

> $$ \dfrac{dx}{dy}=-\sqrt{\dfrac{x}{y}} \text{ when } x,y >0$$

**I suggest that you use your words more carefully.**

Comment: @AakashKumar $\tan{5\pi/4}=\tan{\pi/4}=1$. So there is only one tangent represented by the line $y=x$. By the way delete your earlier comments to prevent overcrowding here in the comments section.

Comment: @AakashKumar Also note that $\sqrt{a} >0$. Substitute $a$ with $\frac{x}{y}$ and see that the slope can't be $-1$.

Comment: This means my fifth step is also incorrect and this will lead to no tangent possible.

Comment: @AakashKumar Your fifth step as correct as you have rejected the negative slope. Equal inclination to axis doesn't necessarily mean slope is $-1$, it can also be $1$, as observed by you in the next step. Please delete some of your earlier comments to prevent overcrowding here in the comments section.

Comment: My fourth step show when I took slope 1 and fifth when slope -1

Comment: @AakashKumar What's your problem? Why don't you read the answer and comments carefully and then reply.